# How do I use command line arguments passed to a shell script that uses xargs?

Tags: shell, find, pipe, xargs, arguments

I have a script that will iterate a set of git checkouts and run a git command in each directory.

I now want to be able to pass a parameter to the shell script from the command line and have that parameter incorporated into the git command being run.

I am using the following script as a test (I've removed the git commands until I can see the parameter being displayed).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune | xargs -P 1 -I {} sh -c 'cd {}; echo `pwd` $1; echo ""'
```

If I run the command with a parameter, I'm expecting to see the name of the directory that contains a .git directory and the parameter.

I only get the directory name.

After a LOT of playing around, I ended up with this ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune | BRANCH="$1" xargs -P 1 -I {} sh -c 'cd {}; echo `pwd` "${BRANCH}"; echo ""'
```

Is there a mechanism I have missed? Is there a "better" way to pass on the arguments?

Comment: @Jeff: OP clearly has tag bash in the interpreter. I don’t see why it shouldn’t be tagged bash

Comment: @Inian None of the code shown depends on `bash`.

Comment: With the she-bang interpreter set to bash, I assumed OP was targeting scripts for bash

Answer (score 1):

From within your shell script you invoke another shell with an in-line script. Since you put this script between single quotes, the `$1` is passed as is. The new shell you just launched, has its own set of parameters, which happen to be empty. So when parsing `$1` it expands to nothing.

In your working example you assign your value to a new variable that is visible in the new shell.

---

If you're just trying to find all git repositories, you may also copy my `all-git` script below. Usage is simple:  `all-git <git command>`, e.g. `all-git status -bs`

```
#!/bin/bash

for repo in `find $PWD -type d -name .git`
do
    repo=${repo%.git}
    ( 
        cd $repo
        echo "${repo%/}: " | sed -e "s#$HOME#~#"
        git "$@"
    )
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. This does seem to be working a lot easier for me that my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune | \
    xargs -P $(nproc) -I {} sh -c "cd \"{}\"; echo \"\$(pwd) $1\"; echo "
```

Should work, but also note that you can call an exported function.

```
OPT="$1"
function doGitWork {
    DIR="$1"
    cd "$DIR"
    echo "$(pwd) $OPT"
}
export -f doGitWork
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune | \
    xargs -P $(nproc) -I {} sh -c "doGitWork \"{}\";"
```

Comment: Good solution, but don't ever inject `{}` into the script that is called from `find` or `xargs`.  Instead: `sh -c 'cd "$1" && printf "%s %s\n" "$(pwd)" "$2"' sh {} "$1"` (or better yet, call it with `-exec` directly from `find` to support all types of filenames)  See also [Is it possible to use \`find -exec sh -c\` safely?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune |
    parallel 'cd {}; echo $(pwd) {}; echo'
```

If you want to do `git pull` in all dirs that have a `.git` dir:

```
allgit() {
  find . -type d -name .git | 
      parallel --tagstring {//} "cd {//}; git $@"
}
allgit pull
```